# How do you send a 503 error page directly with Java sockets

Tags: java, sockets, httpresponse, apache-httpcomponents

I'm trying to build a simple server in Java.

Basically all I have so far is a `ServerSocket` listening on a port. It is working well. I want to implement the servers ability to respond to requests. To begin I want to reply to bad requests with a `503`.

The best idea I have for doing so, is using a `BufferedWriter` to do something like

```
...
 out.write("HTTP/1.0 503 Bad Request\r\n");
 out.write("Date: Mon, 23 Jun 2014 23:59:59 GMT\r\n");
 out.write("Server: Apache/1.3.2\r\n");
...
```

However this seems very error-prone. Also, I've looked at Apache's `HttpComponents` [examples](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/examples/org/apache/http/examples/ElementalHttpServer.java) and they have a built-in class for `HttpResponses` however using them is so complicated and involves a whole infrastructure to be built around them.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to simply return `HttpResponse`s in Java?

Comment: This is why HTTP frameworks exist. Look into Servlets.

Comment: *Why* do you want to do this by hand?

Answer (score 0):

Sending 503 to clients from a plain server socket is not a good idea unless both client and server agree to implement HTTP protocol on both the side.

When dealing with plain socket connections, you are working on the TCP layer of networking stack. Using application logic at the TCP layer is not a good idea and hence the application layer protocols exist such as HTTP.

And unless there is no real need of writing a fresh implementation of a protocol such as HTTP then don't do so. Try to use the existing implementations such as Servlets in java.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well yes, assuming that the socket and server agree on `HTTP`...
I don't want to use servlets in this case

Answer (score -1):

HTTP header ends in double \r\n, so after your last header field, add a second \r\n.